# Python 3.x package structure best practices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a package that's currently structured somewhat like this:

```
food/
    fruit/
        __init__.py
        fruit.py # contains Fruit class
        apple.py # contains Apple class (extends Fruit)
        cherry.py # contains Cherry class (extends Fruit)
```

and `__init__.py` contains something like the following:

```
from .fruit import Fruit
from .apple import Apple
from .cherry import Cherry
```

I put the re-exports in the `__init__.py` file to avoid the slightly more verbose `from food.fruit.apple import Apple` rather than `from food.fruit import Apple`

I'm by no means a Python expert, so I'd appreciate some guidance from those more familiar with the best practices and "Pythonic" ways of doing things.

Comment: if there are all *fruit* classes as such you could you the DRY approach which helps to just re-use the code over again, in your case, this looks good. Although, you could collapse everything into one main file and separate classes within and call those outside of the file structure, that way you won't have to create 3 separate files for these classes.

Comment: I'd be inclined to put them all in one module, but take a look at `__all__` to put into your `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Exactly right!

Your method is perfect and is adopted by many popular libraries like `numpy`, `pandas`, `flask`, etc.

Good insight.